Turn photofilm into projector
I have a photo film, and I want to make an old-style photo projector from it. The problem with simply using the film is that it's the negative of the photo. I figured out 2 solutions:

shoot the negative images and have positive pictures on film and use it
print the images on a transparent film and use it

The first approach fits better to me, because I want to have a handle to also seek through the images, but it's a bit complicated.
The second one sounds better in terms of ease, but as already said, it's a single image on an instance, so I will need a switch-card implementation.
Is there any other way you know?

You present your project in a strange way. You are not "making a projector from a roll of film". What you have is a roll of negatives, and you simply want to project them. In the days when it was common for people to project photos, they shot reversal film, aka slide film - which you can still buy - look for Kodak Ektachrome. There is no easy way to "convert" your negatives to slides. Take note that colour negatives usually include an orange mask - you can't simply take a negative photo of another negative. Consider going back to the beginning and using reversal film right from the start.

What does "I want to have a handle to also seek through the images" mean? And what does "it's a single image on an instance, so I will need a switch-card implementation" mean?

There used to be low-contrast film for slide-duplication purposes.  There might have been negative film with no base color for creating slides from negatives. Neither would still exist at this point.
